# After deployed on Heroku, node app cannot get svg files

Tags: svg, heroku

After I deployed on Heroku, node app cannot get svg files. It works in local. Really not sure why. Here is my code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/img/"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/frontend/")); 
// not sure if serves 2 dir will cause issue?
```

Comment: Ever get a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.